# Self-hosted alternative to hub.docker.com?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, self-hosting, docker-registry, dockerhub

I'd like to set up a private version of hub.docker.com that would let me create a webhook pushed by my private gitlab instance. In other words - when I push to Gitlab, this Docker registry would check out the repository and build it.

I need this to be resistant to malicious Dockerfiles so that the server cannot easily be compromised, revealing contents of all hosted containers. Is there a way I could easily achieve that?

Answer (score 8):

You need to seperately setup the registry and the build server separately. This way when you make a push to GitLab, it notifies the build system (via a POST) and builds the image. After the build is complete, the final image gets pushed to the registry (either self-hosted or to hub.docker.com).

### Setting up the Registry

- First make sure that you have docker installed.
- Then run the following command, which will start an instance of the registry.

  ```
  sudo docker run --restart='always' -d -p 5000:5000 --name=registry \
  -e GUNICORN_OPTS=["--preload"] \
  -v /srv/registry:/tmp/registry \
  registry
  ```
- To expose a Web UI for the above registry, run the following. (Replace  with the IP of the registry)

  ```
  sudo docker run  -d -P --restart='always' \
  -e ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST=<REGISTRY_IP> \
  -e ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT=5000 \
  konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend
  ```

### Setting up the Build Server

- The ubiquitous Jenkins build server can fill in this gap.
- You'll need to install the **GitLab CI plugin** (for Jenkins) which partially emulates the GitLab CI API. Note than you need to also configure the CI plugin after installation from "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System". Note that the private token functionality is not implemented. So enter something random in that field.

  ---

  [image]
- Now you can configure your GitLab repo to fire up a CI event after a PUSH to the repo using **Services** -> **GitLab CI**. 
   **Please Note:** I have tried this out on GitLab v7.7.2. AFAIK the newer GitLab release has interated the earlier seperate GitLab CI.

  ---

  [image]
- On the jenkins server, create a new freestyle project or edit an existing project. Then check *Build on Push Events*.

  ---

  [image: Gitlab CI Push]
- Now for the final step, execute the following code snippet as a shell script. Note that you will need to start your docker daemon with the insecure registry option. Refer: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

  ```
  # Build and push image
  cd $WORKSPACE
  docker build -t <REGISTRY_IP>:5000/<PROJECT_NAME>:latest .
  docker push <REGISTRY_IP>:5000/<PROJECT_NAME>:latest
  ```

#### Alternatively

Have a look at [tarzan](http://nathanleclaire.github.io/tarzan/). It works quite similar to docker hub but it needs to be triggered from a GitHub event (not GitLab). Also because I haven't tried it out, I can't vouch for it.

I suspect that even though **tarzan** is said to work only with GitHub, it might also work with GitLab.

Comment: Tarzan will not be maintained any longer: "DEPRECATED This repository started as a good idea but I didn't have enough time or desire to work on it. So, it's left here for historical / educational purposes, but be advised it's essentially dead code. If anyone else wants to fork and develop / maintain it, be my guest :)" https://github.com/nathanleclaire/tarzan

Answer (score 0):

For the aid of future visitors, GitLab Enterprise Edition has a built in docker image repo now (if it didn't in 2015).  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/container_registry.html

Comment: Difference between [Community Edition or Enterprise Edition | GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/install/ce-or-ee/)